# How to find this sum $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{a_{n}x^n}{n!}=\frac{1}{2-e^x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ such $a_{0}=1$, and such 
$$2a_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a_{k}$$
show that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{a_{n}x^n}{n!}=\dfrac{1}{2-e^x}$$

Comment: First note that the equation for $a_n$ can be made more explicit :
$$
2 a_n= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a_k = a_n +  \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} a_k \implies a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} a_k
$$

Comment: then How to find this sum?

Comment: Make the ansatz $$g(x) = \frac{1}{2-e^x} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{c_n}{n!}x^n$$ (for $\lvert x\rvert < \log 2$), and multiply the power series expansions of $g(x)$ and $2 - e^x$.

Comment: Sum over $n\geqslant1$ the relations $$2\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n=\sum_{k+\ell=n}\frac{a_k}{k!}x^k\,\frac{x^\ell}{\ell!}$$ to deduce that the formal series $$A(x)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n$$ solves $$2\cdot(A(x)-1)=\sum_{k+\ell\geqslant1}\frac{a_k}{k!}x^k\,\frac{x^\ell}{\ell!}=A(x)\,e^x-1$$ and conclude.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n $$

Note that

$$a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} a_k $$

Then

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n = f(x) -1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} a_k $$

Reverse order of summation on RHS:

$$f(x)-1 = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{k!} \sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n-k)!} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{k!} x^k (e^x-1)$$

Therefore,

$$f(x)-1 = f(x) e^x - f(x) $$

or

> $$f(x) = \frac1{2-e^x} $$

NB this is correct when the series converges, i.e., $x \lt \log{2}$.