# Generating function from the recursive equation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, recursion

I need to show that if
$$
a_{n}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{i}a_{i}, 
$$
then
$$
a_{n}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k^{n}}{2^{k}}, 
$$

Solution says:

Since
$$
2a_{n}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}a_{i}
$$

then
$$
A_{e}(x)=\frac{1}{2-e^{x}} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^{x}}{2}\right)^{k} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^{n}}{2^{k}} \cdot \frac{x^n}{n!}
$$

How did we obtain the generating function $A_{e}(x)=\frac{1}{2-e^{x}}$? I understand all the other steps but can solve only simpler recurrences, without sums.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find this sum $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{a_{n}x^n}{n!}=\frac{1}{2-e^x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1943530/how-to-find-this-sum-sum-n-0-infty-fraca-nxnn-frac12-ex) (found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24a_%7Bn%7D%3D%5Csum_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn-1%7D%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bi%7Da_%7Bi%7D%24&p=1))

Comment: @AnneBauval Everything is clear except for one thing.
In the answer, why do we write $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n = f(x) -1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} a_k$ instead of simply $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n = f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} a_k$? Is it so that after changing the order of summation we can write $n=k+1$? Also, thanks for the link to Approach Zero.

Comment: $ f(x) \ne\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} a_k$ because $a_n=\sum_{0\le k<n}\binom nka_k$ holds only for $n\ge1,$ not for $n=0.$ Indeed, $a_0=1,$ whereas $\sum_{0\le k<0}\dots=$ [empty sum = $0.$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum)